# Add message author to store variable for call later

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to store the user the enters the command. I want to be able to call that user later. I get it to work correctly without storing it but once I store it I get errors calling it back. I've also tried to store the whole message and just reference the player but that also didn't seem to work.

```
const Keyv = require("keyv");
const keyv = new Keyv();

execute(message, args) {
(async () => {
  await keyv.set("player1", message.author);

  const player1 = await keyv.get("player1");

  message.channel.send(`${player1}`);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `new keyv()` which means that keyv will just use memory as the storage. Memory is wiped every time your process ends.

You could install the `@keyv/sqlite` module and use he following code which would solve your issue:

```js
const Keyv = require("keyv");
const keyv = new Keyv('sqlite://./db.sqlite');

execute(message, args) {
(async () => {
  await keyv.set("player1", message.author);

  const player1 = await keyv.get("player1");

  message.channel.send(`${player1}`);

})();
```